# How many computers can the retail version of Windows 7 be installed on?

Tags: windows-7

The product key for the RC version allowed it to be installed on up to 3 computers.  Does anybody know how many computers the licence from the full retail version, coming out at the end of this month,will allow you to install it on?

Would be nice if I could put it on my laptop as well as my desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is one for standard retail packs of three if you buy a family pack.

If you buy a fully packaged product, you can install and uninstall as many times as you like as long as it is only installed on one computer at a time.

Comment: I think the definition "used" is inaccurate. I believe "installed" is what counts.

Comment: I said "on one computer at a time"  - laymans terms for installed, and surely used is a redundant extra word but inaccurate? :S Willing to change if others disagree with me.

Comment: "as long as it is only used and " ... And what? ;-)

Comment: I agree that it should be changed from "used" to "installed".  Used could lead one to believe that it could be installed on many machines as long as it is only used on one.  

It is like when I was in the Army...  We were taught to write reports at a General Officer detail level (ie. 4th grade level) thus eliminating confusion.

Comment: @StampedeXV and @pjemmert, changed... sorry, you are right it is better!